# Rails. Mass mail delivering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, mailer, massmail

I have got about 1500 email addresses to send diplomas.

What should I use for bunch delivering nowadays? Ar_mailer looks out-of-date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use **delayed_job** gem to send mail asynchronously.

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: do you create a job for each email you send? do you schedule jobs with which frequency?

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for Madmimi: http://madmimi.com/

And a gem for easy interface: https://github.com/madmimi/madmimi-gem